# How to associate an editor with a problem marker?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have multiple editors registered for my ".custom" file extension. Double clicking on problem markers in the problems view opens the referenced resource in the first registered editor. How can I associate a problem marker with a specific editor, that is used to open the file when the error marker is clicked?

Comment: There is no support for this. The problems view just uses `IDE.openEditor` on the resource in the marker.

Comment: Different editors depending on the view for the same file would be confusing for the user. Instead, consider implementing a quick fix that might open a dialog in case user interaction is required.

Comment: Can you add your comment as answer, so future users will find it more easy? @greg-449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this. The editor for the file in the marker is always used.

The file open is done using the `IDE.openEditor` API, the same as normal file opens. This is done in the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ExtendedMarkersView` base class for marker views in the `openMarkerInEditor` method.